# JAVA LOOP: Sums of a number set

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I am struggling to fix a loop in java, and I'd really appreciate it if someone would be able to help me.

Entire code: http://pastebin.com/C5SQghFa

Loop issues:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){
        for(int j = 1 ; j < length ; j++){          
            if(defaultSet.get(i) + defaultSet.get(j) == sum){
                System.out.println("YUP\n" + defaultSet.get(i) + " " + defaultSet.get(j));
                finalSet.add(defaultSet.get(j));
            }else if(defaultSet.get(i) == sum && !finalSet.contains(defaultSet.get(i))){
                finalSet.add(defaultSet.get(i));
            }else{
                System.out.println("NOPE\n" + defaultSet.get(i) + " " + defaultSet.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to run through an ArrayList twice so I can compare if the sums are equal to a TARGET VALUE the user inputs.

The first if statement simple compares the two values, then adds the value if it works. The second statement sees if a the TARGET VALUE is on the list, and will automatically add it if it is.

The third statement will ignore the output values if they do not equal the TARGET VALUE.

My issue is the loops are not working properly. For some inputs their fine, but for example:

ARRAYLIST: 8, 5, 5, 2

TARGET VALUE: 10

OUTPUT: 5, 5, 5, 5

This is incorrect. The output should be: 8, 5, 5, 2! My loops are skipping the first and last comparisons, and adding extra values that I do not want. Can anyone explain how to set up these loops correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
int endLength = length--;
```

and you should exclude the comparation where i and j are the same.

you are changing the value of the length var.

You implementation has O(n^n) comlexity, there is more efficient ways of implementing that function.

Comment: That was a test value I was using before. I forgot to delete that line. I wasn't using it, but someone pointed out I did have my j = 1, when it should have started at j = 0. So thank you it was the same type of issue I still had in my code!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want that output, you should change 2 lines.

E.g.:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            if (defaultSet.get(i) + defaultSet.get(j) == sum && j != i) {
```

Output (content of `finalSet`):

```
8, 5, 5, 2
```

Notice that:

- `j` starts from `0` to consider all the values
- `j` should be different than `i` => otherwise you get `8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2`

This is an example that works for your **particular example**.

If you want to have something more precise, you should also **provide a rule**.

The expected output for the following input `8, 5, 5, 5, 2` and `10` could be useful. Is it `8, 5, 5, 2` or `8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2` or something else?

What about `8, 5, 2`? Is it `8, 5, 2` or `8, 5, 5, 2` or something else?

Depending on your rule, you could also have (it prints twice an element if it is half of the sum):

```
    boolean ok = true;
    for (int a : defaultSet) {
        for (int b : defaultSet) {
            if (a + b == sum) {
                if (a == b) {
                    if (ok) {
                        finalSet.add(a);
                        finalSet.add(b);
                        ok = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    finalSet.add(a);
                }
            } else if (a == sum && !finalSet.contains(a)) {
                finalSet.add(a);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The most recent addition I made was

    !finalSet.contains

So I had a feeling I needed something like that in the first loop. That fixed my issues perfectly!